# Как вытащить час из timestamp, что бы час 00 минут остался в формате времени?

Tags: postgresql

Есть : `2020-06-13 14:18:05`
Надо : `14:00`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: @Akina я читал эту документацию. Вариант SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-02-16 20:00:00 мне не подходит, так как мне нужно только 20:00

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee70469d2c9ec1d7d332976b9318f5f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40')::time
```